# How to maintain a dynamic height of the pseudo selector ::before?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-selectors, pseudo-element

The UI View has an accordion, where I need to show some connector representation within an accordion and its children and I'm trying to achieve that using an `::before` pseudo-selector for the container inside the parent accordion which has all the children accordions. The left vertical line needs to be stopped at the last intersection of the circle and the horizontal line. In the second sample image, the number of children inside the table is also unknown, I also tried placing the before element using a bottom property.
Any help I could achieve that?

```
 & {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 2rem;
    padding: 0;
  }
  &::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background: #003d76;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 1px;
    display: block;
  }
```

[image: sample image 1]
[image: sample image 2]
[image: sample image 3]

Comment: Positioning at `top` _and_ `bottom` is the way to go, but you need to remove the `height: 100%` for that to work.

Comment: _"The left vertical line needs to be stopped at the last intersection of the circle and the horizontal line."_ - if all of your list items will have the same known height, then factor that in to the `bottom` value. If not, then you can not do it this way, using CSS alone. You could give _each_ list item an `L` shaped line then (or more precise, the upwards part that starts at the circle, and goes up from there), that extends beyond the top of the current item, so that they will overlap. overflow:hidden on the list wrapper can prevent that you see a line extending above the whole list.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this challenge, I have tried to follow the method suggested by @CBroe but there are some unavoidable dependencies that I couldn't change. Tried to make use of an `::after` selector and hide the extra vertical line of the last-child with a white square.

```
.subAccordion {
    & {
      position: relative;
      margin-left: 2rem;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    &::before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      background: #003d76;
      left: 2px;
      height: 100%;
      width: 2px;
      display: block;
    }
    &:last-child::after {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      background: white;
      width: 4%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 51px;
      left: -5px;
    }
  }
```